# Uniform Asymptotic Expansion of a ratio modified Bessel functions of the first kind

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions, approximation-theory

Let $I_{\nu}(\cdot)$ be the modified Bessel function of the first kind of order $\nu$. Can someone please confirm if, when $\nu\rightarrow\infty$, the following approximation

$$\frac{I_{\frac{\nu}{2}}(\frac{\nu}{2}x)}{I_{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}(\frac{\nu}{2}x)}=\frac{x}{1+(1+x^{2})^{1/2}}+O\!\left(\frac{1}{\nu}\right)$$

holds uniformly with respect to $x$? How can I show this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [this paper](https://ia801006.us.archive.org/28/items/arxiv-1110.2089/1110.2089.pdf) and, in particular at equation $(3.3a)$ 
$$\frac{I_{n}(x)}{I_{n-1}(x)}=\frac {x}{2n+x\frac{I_{n+1}(x)}{I_{n}(x)}} $$ you then end with 
$$\frac{I_{n}(nx)}{I_{n-1}(nx)}=\frac {x}{2+x\frac{I_{n+1}(nx)}{I_{n}(nx)}} $$ So, solving for $L$ equation $$L=\frac x{2+x L}\implies L=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

[Kiefer and Weiss](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02764812) showed this more generally. Adapting their result in equation $7a$ to a similar parlance:

$$ \frac{I_{\nu+n}(\nu x)}{I_{\nu}(\nu x)} = \left(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)^n\left(1 - \frac{1+n\sqrt{x^2+1}}{2(x^2+1)}\frac{n}{\nu}+ O\!\left(\frac{1}{\nu^2}\right)\right).$$

Similar relations are given for Hankel functions and additional Bessel functions.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x>0$ and $\nu$ is large and positive. First note that, by [$(10.29.2)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.29.E2),
$$
\frac{{I_\nu  (\nu x)}}{{I_{\nu  - 1} (\nu x)}} = \frac{{I_\nu  (\nu x)}}{{I'_\nu  (\nu x) + (1/x)I_\nu  (\nu x)}} = \cfrac{1}{{\displaystyle\frac{{I'_\nu  (\nu x)}}{{ I_\nu  (\nu x)}} + \frac{1}{x}}}.
$$
If we denote
$$
\eta  = \sqrt {1 + x^2 }  + \log \left( {\frac{x}{{1 + \sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}} \right),
$$
then
$$
I_\nu  (\nu x) = \frac{{\mathrm{e}^{\nu \eta } }}{{\sqrt {2\pi \nu } (1 + x^2 )^{1/4} }}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\nu \sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}} \right)} \right)
$$
and
$$
I'_\nu  (\nu x) = \frac{{(1 + x^2 )^{1/4} \mathrm{e}^{\nu \eta } }}{{\sqrt {2\pi \nu } x}}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\nu \sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}} \right)} \right),
$$
as $\nu\to +\infty$, uniformly with respect to $x>0$. These follow from [$\S10.41.\mathrm{(ii)}$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.41.ii) and the double asymptotic properties of these expansions (cf. [$\S10.41.\mathrm{(iv)}$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.41.iv)). Accordingly,
$$
\frac{{I'_\nu  (\nu x)}}{{I_\nu  (\nu x)}} = \cfrac{{\displaystyle\frac{{(1 + x^2 )^{1/4} \mathrm{e}^{\nu \eta } }}{{\sqrt {2\pi \nu } x}}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\nu \sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}} \right)} \right)}}{{\displaystyle\frac{{\mathrm{e}^{\nu \eta } }}{{\sqrt {2\pi \nu } (1 + x^2 )^{1/4} }}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\nu \sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}} \right)} \right)}} = \frac{{\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}{x} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\nu x}}} \right),
$$
and therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{{I_\nu  (\nu x)}}{{I_{\nu  - 1} (\nu x)}} & = \cfrac{1}{{\displaystyle\frac{{\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}{x} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\nu x}}} \right) + \frac{1}{x}}} = \cfrac{x}{{\displaystyle\sqrt {1 + x^2 }  + 1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{\nu }} \right)}} 
\\ & = \frac{x}{{\sqrt {1 + x^2 }  + 1}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\nu (\sqrt {1 + x^2 }  + 1)^2 }}} \right) = \frac{x}{{\sqrt {1 + x^2 }  + 1}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{\nu }} \right).
\end{align*}
Throughout the whole derivation, the implied constants in the big-$\mathcal{O}$'s are independent of $x$ and $\nu$.