# Uniform Expansion of Ratio of Modified Bessel function

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions, approximation-theory

Let $I_{v}(\cdot)$ be the modified Bessel function of the first kind of order $v$. Does anybody knows an approximation for
$\frac{I_{\frac{v}{2}}(\frac{v}{2}x)}{I_{\frac{v}{2}-1}(\frac{v}{2}x)}$
that holds uniformly with respect to $x$ as $v\rightarrow\infty$?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

I do not know how this has been obtained but, if you look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203477/uniform-asymptotic-expansion-of-a-ratio-modified-bessel-functions-of-the-first-k), a similar question has been asked four says ago (unfortunately, it did not receive any comment or answer). This post asked to confirm that when $v\to \infty$
$$R_v=\frac{I_{\frac{v}{2}}(\frac{v}{2}x)}{I_{\frac{v}{2}-1}(\frac{v}{2}x)}=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}+O\left(\frac{1}{v}\right)$$ which seems to be quite good when compared numerically even for small values of $v$.

Computing the Taylor expansion of $R_{100}$ we get $$R_{100}=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{25 x^3}{204}+\frac{625 x^5}{10608}-\frac{62500
   x^7}{1792089}+O\left(x^9\right)$$ while $$\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^3}{8}+\frac{x^5}{16}-\frac{5 x^7}{128}+O\left(x^{9}\right)$$ which show very similar coefficients.

**Edit**

If you look at [this paper](https://ia801006.us.archive.org/28/items/arxiv-1110.2089/1110.2089.pdf) and, in particular at equation $(3.3a)$ 
$$\frac{I_{n}(x)}{I_{n-1}(x)}=\frac {x}{2n+x\frac{I_{n+1}(x)}{I_{n}(x)}} $$ you then end with 
$$\frac{I_{n}(nx)}{I_{n-1}(nx)}=\frac {x}{2+x\frac{I_{n+1}(nx)}{I_{n}(nx)}} $$ So, solving for $L$ equation $$L=\frac x{2+x L}\implies L=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}$$

Comment: That's really helpfull. Thank you very much. One more thing how would show that the remainder is  $O(1/v)$?